# Control of mutlthreads without sleep function in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

If we are having 10 threads ,out of 10 i want to start first 5 threads at time and after completion/excution  of these 5 threads only i want to start other 5 threads that also should be done automaticlally ,with out using any sleep function in python

```
import threading
import os 
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
now=datetime.now()

print ("starting time ",now)
emptylist=[]
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

def Add(num1):
    num2=1234
    num3=num1+num2
    #print num3
    #print("\n") 
    return num3







#print list


count=0
for i in list:

    t=threading.Thread(target=Add, args=(i,))
    emptylist.append(t)





for j in range(0,len(emptylist)+1,1):
    emptylist[j].start()
    count+=1
    if count%5 ==0:

for k in emptylist:
    k.join()
```

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description. Tell us what you want to do, what you tried and if possible add some sample code. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes,Alexis, i . have tried a little code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is better to avoid using threads manually, and use a  thread pool executor. Something like

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers=5) as executor:
    result = executor.map(Add, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and so on for your other arguments.